# Smooth a function penalising lower values

Tags: confidence-interval, smoothing, interpolation

I have a function $t \rightarrow f(t)$ and its values on a discrete set of time points $t_1, \dots, t_k$.

I want to obtain a smooth approximation of my function $\hat f(t)$. I would have done it with splines or something similar but I want an approximation that penalizes small values.

For example I want the smooth approximation to be exact in $\max_t \approx f(t)$ and given 3 close points $t_1, t_2, t_3$ where $f(t_1) > f(t_2) $ and  $f(t_2) < f(t_3)$  I want $\hat f(t_2) = \dfrac{f(t_1) + f(f_3)}{2}$ or something similar.

The obtained function will be used as upper limit of a confidence interval. For this reason I do not want $\hat f$ to be influenced by the presence of values that are lower than their neighbours due to randomness.

What interpolation technique can I use? Is there a python library that can help me?

Comment: Do you really mean $f(f_3)$ or should it bve $f(t_3)$?